# Exposing EF Model to a variety of clients

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture

Hey guys, I hope everyone is doing well.

I have (more-less) a broad question referring to exposing a model to various clients.

Here is my situation: I have a model (sitting on top of Oracle) that is created using EF 4.0 and 3rd party Oracle provider. The model resides in a library so it can be easily referenced by multiple projects.

My goal is to make the model consumable by as many types of clients as possible:

1. .Net client code (Silverlight, WPF and ASP.Net, services, etc.).
2. MS Office apps (Excel)

Now, I don’t want to get into the business of creating custom methods over the Model (e.g. GetCustomersWhoAreVeryUpsetOrderedByUpsetRank()). I’d like to be able to expose the model in such way that the client code can decide (at run time) how to construct the queries. Should I take in IQueriable, execute it in a service and return the result data set? Or do I let the client do all the work via the model?

I did give oData a shot but it appears that the client side library used to write Linq queries against the model is rather limiting. In addition the protocol does not support updates.

So my question is what is the best approach/technology/implementation in exposing the Model based on the above mentioned criteria?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: oData was designed for precisely this. What did you find "limiting" about the LINQ support? And it does support updates - even transactions and optimistic concurrency.

Comment: Stephen - you are correct; oData is the way to go - apologies for my rather rushed comment earlier about oData. I have done quite a bit of research fin the last 10 days and the verdict is that it will fit nicely in the overall company architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you not to share your model 1:1 with your clients or reuse it 1:1 for different clients.

To share with stakeholders, use some simple [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). The mapping code can be created automatically with a CASE tool, T4 transformation or any other source code creation. If you share your own model, you run into problems as soon as you have to / want to refactor something or if one client has some specific requirements.

Almost same depends on the query methods from EF (the DAL). Define some [DataMappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) interfaces with common requirements and implement a default behavior. If you ever need your `GetCustomersWhoAreVeryUpsetOrderedByUpsetRank()`, you are sill fine since you can add this query to a data mapper deriving from the default mapper. With this approach the core system stays clear and reusable and each client is able to get her/his custom features.